Adding authentication component to versionned API
URL being accessed: /api/v1/requests - using Cake - Setup routing to support versioned API controllers? as inspiration
The goal is to load my own custom authentication, however, it's partially loading based on the dd() appearing/not appearing.
Instead, I'm seeing Missing Route Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingRouteException, for a route that would never exist and I suspect is coming from the root application's authentication.
Code in routes.php
$routes->prefix('Api', ['path' => '/api', '_namePrefix' =>'rest:' ], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        
    $builder->setExtensions(['json']);

    //connect parent /api to index, show welcome screen, instructions on how to get access
    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'index']);
    
    //routing child level /v1
    $builder->prefix('V1', ['path' => '/v1'], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        $builder->connect('/:controller');
    });

    //routing child level /v2
    $builder->prefix('V2', ['path' => '/v2'], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        $builder->connect('/:controller');
    });
});

Lastly, I strategically placed dd() that aren't being displayed.
Custom authentication location:
/src/Auth/ApiAuthComponent.php
/src/Auth/ApiAuthenticate.php

Controller locations:
/src/Controller/Api/V1/RequestController.php
/src/Controller/Api/AppController.php

Code attempting to load the custom authentication /src/Controller/Api/AppController.php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Api;

//...

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize():void
    {
        //parent::initialize();
        //dd("here A"); //works

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => true, //function below ?
        ]);
        
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event)
    {
        
        //parent::beforeFilter($event);
        //dd("here B"); //works

        $this->Auth->setConfig('authenticate', [
            'Api'   //supposed to be custom auth in /src/Auth?
        ]);

        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    }

    public function beforeRedirect(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event, mixed $url, \Cake\Http\Response $response) 
    {
        dd("here C"); //doesn't work
        $this->login();
        $this->render();
        return false;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        dd("here D");   //doesn't work
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        //logged in
        if ($user) 
        {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);

            $this->{$act}(); // consumer has been authenticated, proceed with controller / action
        } 
        else 
        {
            $text = [
                'message' => 'Access denied.',
            ];

            $this->set('text', $text);

            $this->viewBuilder()
                ->setOption('serialize', 'text')
                ->setClassName('Json');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
    }

    public function isAuthorized($user = null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function viewClasses(): array
    {
        return [JsonView::class];
    }
}
?>

Code in src/Auth/ApiAuthComponent:
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;

class ApiAuthComponent extends AuthComponent {

var $components = array('Flash'); 

public function identify() {
    dd("api auth identify");    //doesn't work
    if (empty($this->_authenticateObjects)) {
        $this->constructAuthenticate();
    }
    foreach ($this->_authenticateObjects as $auth) {
        $result = $auth->authenticate($this->request, $this->response);
        if (!empty($result) && is_array($result)) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>

Edit #1
The missing route is:
"array ( 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => NULL, 'prefix' => 'Api/V1', '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.

Hadn't included the entire routes as I had assumed it was irrelevant as I wasn't calling the root path.
Users.login would be called for authentication when accessing any other path than /api due to the authentication configured in /src/Controller/AppController.php (noting, 2 separate AppControllers.php files in my code ATM)
Full routes.php:
<?php

return static function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->setRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

    $routes->scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        
        $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
        $builder->fallbacks();
    });

    
    //routing top level /api
    $routes->prefix('Api', ['path' => '/api', '_namePrefix' =>'rest:' ], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
        
        $builder->setExtensions(['json']);

        //connect parent /api to index, show welcome screen, instructions on how to get access
        $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'index']);
        
        //routing child level /v1
        $builder->prefix('V1', ['path' => '/v1'], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
            $builder->connect('/:controller');
        });

        //routing child level /v2
        $builder->prefix('V2', ['path' => '/v2'], function (RouteBuilder $builder) {
            $builder->connect('/:controller');
        });
    });

};

Edit #2
Output of bin/cake routes:
| api/v2:_controller:index            | /api/v2/:controller                       |          | Api/V2 |             | index             |           |
| api/v1:_controller:index            | /api/v1/:controller                       |          | Api/V1 |             | index             |           |
| users:login                         | /                                         |          |        | Users       | login             |           |
| _controller:index                   | /{controller}                             |          |        |             | index             |           |
| _controller:_action                 | /{controller}/{action}/*                  |          |        |             | index             |           |


What route is it saying is missing?

@GregSchmidt see edit 1, which includes the full routes and missing route.

So it appears that it's trying to authenticate the call, failing, and redirecting to a login page in the 'Api/V1' prefix. Which part of this is incorrect according to your expected behaviour? The authentication, the failure, the fact that it redirects, or the URL that it's redirecting to?

I believe, with my current setup, it shouldn't redirect to Users.login, since it's src/Controller/api/AppController.php that's being partially called (parses header for auth) and not src/Controller/AppController.php which uses Controller authentication (thus Users.login). Hope this makes sense. I may have misunderstood how this works.

That gets beyond my knowledge of authentication, but hopefully it clarifies the problem for somebody who knows more about it.

Maybe I should rephrase the whole thing to essentially ask, how do AppControllers get called in relation to their location? Thanks for having a go!
